# How to convert Expo project into React Native Cli mode?

Tags: react-native

I'd like to convert existing Expo project into React Native cli mode.
This is `App.js` file in root directory.
Is there anything that corresponding to "AppLoading" in Expo?
As a result of Googling, I found that splash screen is the key, but I don't know how to use it well.
*How can I compose this App.js file ?*

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

import productsReducer from './store/reducers/products';
import cartReducer from './store/reducers/cart';
import ordersReducer from './store/reducers/orders';
import authReducer from './store/reducers/auth';
import NavigationContainer from './navigation/NavigationContainer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  products: productsReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
  orders: ordersReducer,
  auth: authReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    'open-sans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
    'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf')
  });
};

export default function App() {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (!fontLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => {
          setFontLoaded(true);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: read this if it helps: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/

Answer (score 2):

From the [expo](https://web.archive.org/web/20190705150420/https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/) documentation:

In the project directory, run:

```
expo eject
```

This will download the required dependencies and build native projects under the ios and android directories.